# Reduce the size of a file

Tags: linux, centos, files, filesystems

I have two files, each one contain more than 3GB in `/var/log` partition, I need to free some space without deleting or moving the files cause it will interrupt my system.

I also can't delete the lines in files with `vi + dd`. There are thousands of lines.

Any useful ideas?

Files:

1- `messages`

2-  My web server log file.

Comment: why not just rotate/gzip those?

Comment: rotate with `logrotate` ? and if so does it need extra space like `split`cause i dont have any space left.

Comment: Logrotate will gzip the file it does't need any extra space. it will use new file instead

Comment: Would it be a problem to lose a few (new) log entries?

Comment: @Mongrel Because `gzip` writes to a new file it *does* need additional space. And a lot of it if the file being compressed is large. When `gzip` is finished you need less space that before it started but that does not help you at all in the meantime.

Comment: Additional space will not be required in `/var/log` path, it will use `/tmp` for compress.

Comment: @HaukeLaging its critical, i can only delete old logs

Comment: @Mongrel That is not what my version (gzip 1.8) does. With a quick look I did not notice any option in the man page to activate such behaviour.

Comment: @Mongrel `gzip` does not use `/tmp` as a workspace. It creates (and writes) the compressed file to the same location in the filesystem as the file being compressed. To get around this one would have to use a pipe-and-move solution.

Comment: Are the files you wish to reduce in size currently being written to? What part of the files would you like to delete? Can you describe what will break if the files are moved?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `messages` is one of the files, the other one is related to my web server, any deleting or moving of the file will stop my server.

Comment: Then you have specified an impossible set of requirements: 1. There's no more space on the filesystem. 2. You want to get more space. 3. You don't (or can't) move or shrink any of the existing files.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to truncate the files, which unlike using `rm` will release the disk space even if the files are still open:

```
> /var/log/big1.log
> /var/log/big2.log
```

But please test it on a separate system first.  Check if the file's inode numbers change.  If not, you're good.

Comment: @roaima  I don't see where  OP asks for compression.  In any case, he can save the current contents elsewhere, before truncation.  I checked with a file open for writing,  space was freed.

Comment: @roaima no problem.  Again, I verified what I said.  You are referring to the deletion of a file that is open.  That is not what the shell does with ">".

Comment: @roaima  That's what mondays are for.

Comment: This completely remove the contain of the file,i tested this then i applied this only on `messages` after backing up my file.

Comment: That is indeed what I meant by "truncate".  You should now implement log rotation to prevent this from happening again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the full content of the existing files you will need to compress them to some temporary space elsewhere and then replace each uncompressed file with its compressed equivalent. Otherwise just delete the older log files or archive them elsewhere.

Here is a proposal to compress the log files without losing their contents. However, you need to be aware that if you keep growing log files it will only defer the problem of your filesystem filling up and not resolve it permanently.

Identify the older files that are to be compressed. (None of these must be in use or open *right now* for logging.) In my example this is `big1.log`.

Identify a chunk of filesystem that can hold the largest of these uncompressed files. In my example I'm going to assume this is `/home`.

In your real-world scenario you can use a `for` loop to iterate across a series of files. Here are the steps for a single file:

```
logfile='/var/log/big1.log'                      # The logfile to be compressed

if gzip -c "$logfile" >/home/log.gz
then
    touch --reference "$logfile" /home/log.gz    # Capture timestamp of last update
    chown --reference "$logfile" /home/log.gz    # Capture ownerships
    chmod --reference "$logfile" /home/log.gz    # Capture permissions
    rm -f "$logfile"                             # Make space
    mv -f /home/log.gz "$logfile.gz"             # Rename with correct suffix
fi
```